# File object has no attribute encode- BeautifulSoup and Python

Tags: python, encoding, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to figure out the best way to parse a HTML file and make sure I'm dealing with entirely in utf-8 format. Currently I have:

```
fileName = open(givenDir +"/"+ aFile, "r").encode('utf8')
soup = BeautifulSoup(fileName)
```

And I continue on my way. These are all local files. But it says that file object has no attribute encode. If I take out the encode bit, it all works fine, however when I go to print out letters with the following bit of code:

```
for word, count in wordList:
    wordFile.write("%s: %d\n" % (word.encode('utf8'), count))
```

A message comes up with "Warning:root:Some characters could not be decoded, and were replaced with REPLACEMENT CHARACTER", which leads me to believe nothing was really encoded properly to begin with?

Can anyone clarify this for me?

Answer (score 0):

`open()` returns a file object.

If you want to get the contents of the file, use `file.read()` or `file.readline()` or `file.readlines()`

So that would make your code:

```
fileName = open(givenDir +"/"+ aFile, "r").read().encode('utf8')
soup = BeautifulSoup(fileName)
```

Comment: So that solved the initial problem (thanks!) but now I get: UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x8a in position 8611: invalid start byte. What's the workaround for this one?

Comment: Are you sure that the 'ascii' error is from the same place as the previous problem? If all went smoothly here, any function that requires ascii produce errors. My guess (without seeing the rest of the code) is that your ascii error is from the next step.